# With string arrays when reading from a file

Tags: c

I have a problem when trying to read from a .txt file,
file example:"12345 qwe>rty 12345 q=wert qe/ry"trying to read more than 50 000 similar lines, compare them with another (also read from doc.) array, but the programe brakes every time...
the code suposte to compare 2 arrays and if they match print them in new doc. hope i explained well...`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max 57000

main()
{
  int i, j, n;
  char (*ime[200])[max], (*grad[200])[max], (*adresa[200])[max];
  int rb[max], rbk[max], posta[max], check[max];
  FILE *svi = fopen("C:\\Users\\Fujitsu\\Desktop\\001.txt", "r");
  FILE *kupci = fopen("C:\\Users\\Fujitsu\\Desktop\\002txt", "r");
  FILE *izlaz = fopen("C:\\Users\\Fujitsu\\Desktop\\003.txt", "w");
  //  reading from 001.txt//
  // 
  printf("1");    //some kind of check point
  for (i = 2; i < 56300; i++)
  {
    fscanf(svi, "%d%s%d%s%s", &rb[i], &ime[i], &posta[i], &grad[i], &adresa[i]);
    check[i] = 0;
    fscanf(kupci, "%d", &n);
    rbk[n] = 0;
  }
  //matching 001 i 002//
  printf("2");
  for (i = 2; i < 56300; i++)
  {
    if (check[i] == rbk[i])
    {
      check[i] = 1;
    }
    //stampanje u novu datoteku 003 //
    if (check[i] == 0)
    {
      fprintf(izlaz, "%szt%d\t%s\t%s\t\n", ime[i], posta[i], grad[i],
          adresa[i]);
      ;
    }
  }
  fclose(svi);
  fclose(kupci);
  fclose(izlaz);
  printf("done");
  getch();
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Please format your code better.  That might even help you find the bug.

Comment: Please explain more detailed what "*... but the programe brakes every time. ...*" means.

Comment: Also, are you sure the pointer-to-array declarations (like `char (*ime[200])[max]`) are really what you want?

Comment: @CarlNorum , I am not it was some kind of a try, All i what to do is when i match 2 numbers from first row of file to read all the rest of the line (I tried to put them in arrays of strings) but something is not functioning...

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here.  The likely immediate cause of trouble is that you don't check that you open the files successfully, and one of the names is missing its `.`:

```
FILE *svi   = fopen("C:\\Users\\Fujitsu\\Desktop\\001.txt", "r");
FILE *kupci = fopen("C:\\Users\\Fujitsu\\Desktop\\002txt", "r");  // <<-- .txt???
FILE *izlaz = fopen("C:\\Users\\Fujitsu\\Desktop\\003.txt", "w");
```

It is not clear that the `rbk` array is initialized properly.

It is clear that you do not want the pointers to arrays in:

```
char (*ime[200])[max], (*grad[200])[max], (*adresa[200])[max];
```

Frankly, those are mind blowing; they're also completely wrong for the purpose at hand.  Macros are conventionally written in all upper-case, too (so `MAX` rather than `max`).  You are probably looking for:

```
char ime[MAX][200], grad[MAX][200], adresa[MAX][200];
```

These are three arrays of `MAX` entries each, with each entry being 200 characters long.  This is at least 'sensible' in that it gives you allocated space to read into; it is not sensible in that it probably wastes a lot of space, but at least it shouldn't crash on you.

Your code should check that the `fscanf()` calls succeed.  The arguments to the first `fscanf()` call need fixing to recognize that `ime[i]` etc are arrays and do not need the `&` in front of them.  Check point print statements need to end with a newline; otherwise, they do not appear in a timely fashion.  I dislike trailing blanks and tabs at the end of output lines, too.

All in all, these changes yield:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 57000

int main(void)
{
    int i, n;
    char ime[MAX][200], grad[MAX][200], adresa[MAX][200];
    int rb[MAX], rbk[MAX], posta[MAX], check[MAX];
    FILE *svi   = fopen("C:\\Users\\Fujitsu\\Desktop\\001.txt", "r");
    FILE *kupci = fopen("C:\\Users\\Fujitsu\\Desktop\\002.txt", "r");
    FILE *izlaz = fopen("C:\\Users\\Fujitsu\\Desktop\\003.txt", "w");

    if (svi == 0 || kupci == 0 || izlaz == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open at least one file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(rbk, '\xFF', sizeof(rbk));  // Not zero - that's too friendly.

    printf("1\n");    //some kind of check point
    for (i = 2; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (fscanf(svi, "%d%s%d%s%s", &rb[i], ime[i], &posta[i], grad[i], adresa[i]) != 5)
            break;
        check[i] = 0;
        if (fscanf(kupci, "%d", &n) != 1)
            break;
        rbk[n] = 0;
    }
    int max = i;

    printf("2\n");
    for (i = 2; i < max; i++)
    {
        if (check[i] == rbk[i])
            check[i] = 1;
        if (check[i] == 0)
            fprintf(izlaz, "%s\t%d\t%s\t%s\n", ime[i], posta[i], grad[i], adresa[i]);
    }
    fclose(svi);
    fclose(kupci);
    fclose(izlaz);
    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without warnings.  I can't work out how the files are meant to be organized; it seems likely that `002.txt` does not simply contain the number 1..N in order, but it is not clear how they are supposed to be sequenced.  So, the code is untested, not least because I don't have a `C:` drive on my Unix machine.  However, that's a different problem. (It's also laziness: I could perfectly well create a file `C:\Users\Fujitsu\001.txt` in my current directory...)